# Rust: using derive inside macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros

i have a question on rust macros... i created a custom trait, and i made it derivable...
but now if i try to derive the trait inside a macro it doesn't work (but if i write it manually it does work)

here is the code:

```rust
// this is my macro
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! compact {
    ( $x:ident, $y:ident ) => {
        #[derive(Vhdlizable,Debug)]
        struct Compact<T,E>{
            $x: T,
            $y: E
        }
    };
}
#[test]
fn test_compact_macro(){
    let a = 11_i32;
    let b = 0_u8;

    //this dos't work
    //compact!(a,b);

    //this works
    #[derive(Vhdlizable,Debug)]
    struct Compact<T, E,> {
        a: T,
        b: E,
    }
}
```

the error i get is the following:

```
error[E0424]: expected value, found module `self`
   --> src\tests.rs:103:14
    |
90  |         #[derive(Vhdlizable,Debug)]
    |                  ---------- this function has a `self` parameter, but a macro invocation can only access identifiers it receives from parameters
...
103 |     compact!(a,b);
    |              ^ `self` value is a keyword only available in methods with a `self` parameter
```

i have no idea what could cause this...

it should be noted that if i only derive the Debug trait it works

here is the code to make the trait Derivable:

```rust
use proc_macro2::TokenStream;
use quote::{quote, quote_spanned};
use syn::spanned::Spanned;
use syn::{
    parse_macro_input, parse_quote, Data, DeriveInput, Fields, GenericParam, Generics,
};


#[test]
fn test(){

}


#[proc_macro_derive(Vhdlizable)]
pub fn derive_vhdliizable(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {

    // Parse the input tokens into a syntax tree.
    let input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);

    // Used in the quasi-quotation below as `#name`.
    let name = input.ident;

    // Add a bound `T: HeapSize` to every type parameter T.
    let generics = add_trait_bounds(input.generics);
    let (impl_generics, ty_generics, where_clause) = generics.split_for_impl();


    let necessary_bits = sum_necessary_bits(&input.data);

    let bit_rapresentation = concat_bit_representation(&input.data);

    let declaration_code = generate_delcaration_code(&input.data);

    let construction_code = generate_construction_code(&input.data);

    let deconstruction_code = generate_deconstruction_code(&input.data);

    let recreate_from_bits_code = generate_recursive_reconstruction(&input.data);

    let expanded = quote! {

        // The generated impl.
        impl #impl_generics Vhdlizable for #name #ty_generics #where_clause {


            fn get_necessary_bits() -> usize{
                #necessary_bits
            }

            fn get_bit_representation(&self) -> Vec<bool>{
                #bit_rapresentation
            }

            fn construct_from_bits(data: &[bool]) -> Result<Self,std::io::Error> where Self: Sized{

                if data.len() != Self::get_necessary_bits(){
                    return Err(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Length of input incompatible with length of output"));
                };

                #recreate_from_bits_code
            }

            fn get_vhd_construction_code(variable_name: &str ,start_index: usize) -> String{
                #construction_code
            }

            fn get_vhd_declaration_code(variable_name: &str ) -> String{
                #declaration_code
            }

            fn get_vhd_deconstruction_code(variable_name: &str ,start_index: usize) -> String{
                #deconstruction_code
            }

        }
    };

    // Hand the output tokens back to the compiler.
    proc_macro::TokenStream::from(expanded)

}

// Add a bound `T: Vhdlizable` to every type parameter T.
fn add_trait_bounds(mut generics: Generics) -> Generics {
    for param in &mut generics.params {
        if let GenericParam::Type(ref mut type_param) = *param {
            type_param.bounds.push(parse_quote!(Vhdlizable));
        }
    }
    generics
}

// Generate an expression to sum up the heap size of each field.
fn sum_necessary_bits(data: &Data) -> TokenStream {
    match *data {
        Data::Struct(ref data) => {
            match data.fields {
                Fields::Named(ref fields) => {
                    let recurse = fields.named.iter().map(|f| {
                        let type_ = &f.ty;
                        quote_spanned! {f.span()=>
                            #type_::get_necessary_bits()
                        }
                    });
                    quote! {
                        0 #(+ #recurse)*
                    }
                }
                Fields::Unnamed(_) => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unnamed Type")
                }
                Fields::Unit => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unit Type")
                }
            }
        }
        Data::Enum(_) | Data::Union(_) => unimplemented!(),
    }
}

fn concat_bit_representation(data: &Data) -> TokenStream {

    match *data {
        Data::Struct(ref data) => {
            match data.fields {
                Fields::Named(ref fields) => {
                    let recurse: Vec<_> = fields.named.iter().map(|f| {
                        let name = &f.ident;
                        quote_spanned! {f.span()=>
                            self.#name.get_bit_representation()
                        }
                    }).collect();

                    quote! {
                        let mut v = vec![false;0];
                        #(v.extend(#recurse);)*
                        v
                    }
                }
                Fields::Unnamed(_) => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unnamed Type")
                }
                Fields::Unit => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unit Type")
                }
            }
        }
        Data::Enum(_) | Data::Union(_) => unimplemented!(),
    }
}


fn generate_delcaration_code(data: &Data) -> TokenStream {

    match *data {
        Data::Struct(ref data) => {
            match data.fields {
                Fields::Named(ref fields) => {
                    let recurse: Vec<_> = fields.named.iter().map(|f| {
                        let name = &f.ident;
                        let type_ = &f.ty;
                        quote_spanned! {f.span()=>
                            //self.#name.get_delcaration_code("name")
                            #type_::get_vhd_declaration_code(
                                &format!("{}_{}",variable_name,stringify!(#name))[..]
                            )
                        }
                    }).collect();


                    quote! {
                        let mut s = String::new();
                        #(s.push_str(&(#recurse)[..]);)*
                        s
                    }
                }
                Fields::Unnamed(_) => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unnamed Type")
                }
                Fields::Unit => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unit Type")
                }
            }
        }
        Data::Enum(_) | Data::Union(_) => unimplemented!(),
    }
}


fn generate_construction_code(data: &Data) -> TokenStream {

    match *data {
        Data::Struct(ref data) => {
            match data.fields {
                Fields::Named(ref fields) => {
                    let recurse: Vec<_> = fields.named.iter().map(|f| {
                        let name = &f.ident;
                        let type_ = &f.ty;
                        quote_spanned! {f.span()=>
                            #type_::get_vhd_construction_code(
                                &format!("{}_{}",variable_name,stringify!(#name))[..],
                                start_from
                            )
                        }
                    }).collect();

                    let sizes: Vec<_> = fields.named.iter().map(|f| {
                        let type_ = &f.ty;
                        quote_spanned! {f.span()=>
                            #type_::get_necessary_bits()
                        }
                    }).collect();

                    quote! {
                        let mut start_from = start_index;
                        let mut s = String::new();
                        #(
                            s.push_str(&(#recurse)[..]);
                            start_from += #sizes;
                        )*
                        s
                    }
                }
                Fields::Unnamed(_) => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unnamed Type")
                }
                Fields::Unit => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unit Type")
                }
            }
        }
        Data::Enum(_) | Data::Union(_) => unimplemented!(),
    }
}

fn generate_deconstruction_code(data: &Data) -> TokenStream {

    match *data {
        Data::Struct(ref data) => {
            match data.fields {
                Fields::Named(ref fields) => {
                    let recurse: Vec<_> = fields.named.iter().map(|f| {
                        let name = &f.ident;
                        let type_ = &f.ty;
                        quote_spanned! {f.span()=>
                            #type_::get_vhd_deconstruction_code(
                                &format!("{}_{}",variable_name,stringify!(#name))[..],
                                start_from
                            )
                        }
                    }).collect();

                    let sizes: Vec<_> = fields.named.iter().map(|f| {
                        let type_ = &f.ty;
                        quote_spanned! {f.span()=>
                            #type_::get_necessary_bits()
                        }
                    }).collect();

                    quote! {
                        let mut start_from = start_index;
                        let mut s = String::new();
                        #(
                            s.push_str(&(#recurse)[..]);
                            start_from += #sizes;
                        )*
                        s
                    }
                }
                Fields::Unnamed(_) => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unnamed Type")
                }
                Fields::Unit => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unit Type")
                }
            }
        }
        Data::Enum(_) | Data::Union(_) => unimplemented!(),
    }
}


fn generate_recursive_reconstruction(data: &Data) -> TokenStream {

    match *data {
        Data::Struct(ref data) => {
            match data.fields {
                Fields::Named(ref fields) => {
                    let recurse: Vec<_> = fields.named.iter().map(|f| {
                        let name = &f.ident;
                        let type_ = &f.ty;
                        quote_spanned! {f.span()=>

                            let n = #type_::get_necessary_bits();

                            let v = &data[counter..(counter+n)];

                            counter += n;

                            let #name: #type_ = #type_::construct_from_bits(v)?;
                        }
                    }).collect();

                    let names: Vec<_> = fields.named.iter().map(|f| {
                        let name = &f.ident;
                        quote_spanned! {f.span()=>
                            #name
                        }
                    }).collect();


                    quote! {

                        let mut counter = 0_usize;

                        #(
                            #recurse
                        )*


                        Ok(Self{
                            #(
                            #names,
                            )*
                        })
                    }
                }
                Fields::Unnamed(_) => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unnamed Type")
                }
                Fields::Unit => {
                    unimplemented!("Impossible to derive this trait on unit Type")
                }
            }
        }
        Data::Enum(_) | Data::Union(_) => unimplemented!(),
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code that makes `Vhdlizable` derivable

Comment: You may need to expand the macro, as the error sometimes gets pinned on the `#[derive]` line, but really it's deep in the guts of your deriver.

Comment: Please include the macro-expanded code (cargo expand) of your example (with the macro call uncommented).

Answer (score 0):

i switch to nightly rust to expand the code... and it works now...

if you are still interested in or, here is the expanded code:

```rust
#[allow(unused_imports)]
#[allow(dead_code)]
mod tests {
    use std::fmt::Debug;
    #[allow(unused_imports)]
    use crate::communicate_to_vhdl::{Communicator, Vhdlizable};
    fn test_compact_macro() {
        let a = 11_i32;
        let b = 0_u8;
        struct Compact<T, E> {
            a: T,
            b: E,
        }
        impl<T: Vhdlizable, E: Vhdlizable> Vhdlizable for Compact<T, E> {
            fn get_necessary_bits() -> usize {
                0 + T::get_necessary_bits() + E::get_necessary_bits()
            }
            fn get_bit_representation(&self) -> Vec<bool> {
                let mut v = ::alloc::vec::from_elem(false, 0);
                v.extend(self.a.get_bit_representation());
                v.extend(self.b.get_bit_representation());
                v
            }
            fn construct_from_bits(data: &[bool]) -> Result<Self, std::io::Error>
                where
                    Self: Sized,
            {
                if data.len() != Self::get_necessary_bits() {
                    return Err(
                        std::io::Error::new(
                            std::io::ErrorKind::Other,
                            "Length of input incompatible with length of output",
                        ),
                    );
                }
                let mut counter = 0_usize;
                let n = T::get_necessary_bits();
                let v = &data[counter..(counter + n)];
                counter += n;
                let a: T = T::construct_from_bits(v)?;
                let n = E::get_necessary_bits();
                let v = &data[counter..(counter + n)];
                counter += n;
                let b: E = E::construct_from_bits(v)?;
                Ok(Self { a, b })
            }
            fn get_vhd_construction_code(
                variable_name: &str,
                start_index: usize,
            ) -> String {
                let mut start_from = start_index;
                let mut s = String::new();
                s.push_str(
                    &(T::get_vhd_construction_code(
                        &{
                            let res = ::alloc::fmt::format(
                                format_args!("{0}_{1}", variable_name, "a"),
                            );
                            res
                        }[..],
                        start_from,
                    ))[..],
                );
                start_from += T::get_necessary_bits();
                s.push_str(
                    &(E::get_vhd_construction_code(
                        &{
                            let res = ::alloc::fmt::format(
                                format_args!("{0}_{1}", variable_name, "b"),
                            );
                            res
                        }[..],
                        start_from,
                    ))[..],
                );
                start_from += E::get_necessary_bits();
                s
            }
            fn get_vhd_declaration_code(variable_name: &str) -> String {
                let mut s = String::new();
                s.push_str(
                    &(T::get_vhd_declaration_code(
                        &{
                            let res = ::alloc::fmt::format(
                                format_args!("{0}_{1}", variable_name, "a"),
                            );
                            res
                        }[..],
                    ))[..],
                );
                s.push_str(
                    &(E::get_vhd_declaration_code(
                        &{
                            let res = ::alloc::fmt::format(
                                format_args!("{0}_{1}", variable_name, "b"),
                            );
                            res
                        }[..],
                    ))[..],
                );
                s
            }
            fn get_vhd_deconstruction_code(
                variable_name: &str,
                start_index: usize,
            ) -> String {
                let mut start_from = start_index;
                let mut s = String::new();
                s.push_str(
                    &(T::get_vhd_deconstruction_code(
                        &{
                            let res = ::alloc::fmt::format(
                                format_args!("{0}_{1}", variable_name, "a"),
                            );
                            res
                        }[..],
                        start_from,
                    ))[..],
                    "Compact",
                    "a",
                    &self.a,
                    "b",
                    &&self.b,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```